# Error while importing modules in Python

Tags: python, import, gdata

I want to be able to import the following Google Data Python Modules:
    atom.data, 
    gdata.sites.client,
    gdata.sites.data

I've gone ahead and downloaded the files and even made changes to the PYTHONPATH variable as recommended here [link] ([How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)). Despite this I get an error stating:
    Import error No module named atom.data.
What am I doing wrong? I've placed the GData files inside the Python27 folder.

THE CODE (JUST IN CASE):

```
#!C:\Python27

import atom.data
import gdata.sites.client
import gdata.sites.data

client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(source='i-l-v1', site='intratrial2', domain='inmobi.com')
client.ClientLogin('', '', client.source)

feed = client.GetSiteFeed()

for entry in feed.entry:
  print '%s (%s)' % (entry.title.text, entry.site_name.text)
  if entry.summary.text:
    print 'description: ' + entry.summary.text
  if entry.FindSourceLink():
    print 'this site was copied from site: ' + entry.FindSourceLink()
  print 'acl feed: %s\n' % entry.FindAclLink()
  print 'theme: ' + entry.theme.text
```

Comment: Not sure, but try `from atom import data`

Comment: Not working. Is there an issue running gdata-2.0.18 with Python 27?

Comment: Will re-installing Python help in the slightest?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, I did a "pip install gdata" within a virtual environment and then created a symbolic link to gdata.  That worked for me.

```
$source venv/bin/activate
$pip install gdata
$deactivate
$ln -s venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata .
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing it using ./setup.py install. It will do all the necessary things and  you don't have to set any path from your side. Refer https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib?csw=1 for more details.

Comment: I did. It says that 'src/atom' is missing. I double checked. Atom is exactly where its supposed to be.

Comment: How you are installing? Go into the folder where install.py is present then do a install.